# AWSでローカルIPのみを疎通可能にしたい

Tags: aws

AWSでpublic ipは疎通できないようにして、ローカルipだけ疎通させたい場合、どのように設定すればよろしいでしょうか？
おそらく、security groupでICMPの設定が必要だと思うのですが、詳しい方、ご教示ください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: AWS のサービスのうちどれに対する疎通のことでしょうか? security group ということは EC2 でしょうか?

Comment: 説明不足でも申し訳ありません。EC2になります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

インスタンスのセキュリティグループでインバウンドという項目があります。
そこに、0.0.0.0/32(IPアドレス/32)を入力してください。/32はどんなIPでも必須です。

Answer (score 0):

EC2 での疎通の設定は Security Group で行います。
Security Group では Inbound/Outbound それぞれに対し、相手の IP アドレスとポート番号とプロトコルを組みにして疎通可能な通信を設定できます。通信相手が EC2 インスタンスの場合は、IP アドレスの代わりに、その EC2 インスタンスに設定されている Security Group を指定することもできます。こうすると複数の同じ Security Group を使っている EC2 インスタンスに対して同じ設定を行うことができます。

参考: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Answer (score 0):

疎通というのが、ICMPだけであればSecurity Groupで制限するのが良いかと思います。

逆に、あらゆる通信をローカルIP（＝プライベートIPアドレス）のみに制限したいのであれば、VPC内にプライベートサブネットを作成し該当のサーバをそのサブネットに配置するのが良いかと思います。プライベートサブネットというのは、そのサブネットのRoute Tableのルーティング先にIGW (Intenet Gateway）が無い構成にしておくということです。